# Piranha CMS Deploying site using VS Web Publish loses images

Tags: piranha-cms

I'm using Visual Studio publish to deploy a site using Piranha CMS to a web server. Whenever I deploy the actual image content is lost and I have to upload the image file again to restore it. The database isn't altered during the deployment process, all relations between regions, pages and content remain.

There is nothing in the documentation I can find that covers this, can anyone help?

Comment: No sooner had I posted the question than I found the answer. I'll leave this up in case it helps anyone else though. To avoid the image files being removed on publish, in the publish profile, Settings, File Publish Options ensure the 'Exclude Files from the App_Data folder' option is ticked.